# Flutter: What is the best practice to save general configurations of app?

Tags: file, flutter, mobile, config

I have a flutter application where there are some small configs such as Audio enabled/disabled.
I tried to use "`package:global_configuration/global_configuration.dart`" but that is being reset after app restart.
I did not include any DataBase yet and want to get rid of that as for now these configs are the only things I need to keep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are loads of options. All of them are based on storing data locally though. The best are:

- Hive: https://pub.dev/packages/hive
- SQLite: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite
- SharedPreferences: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Comment: Close your eyes, https://pub.dev/packages/hive is the best

Answer (score -1):

I would definitely recommend you to use SharedPreferences . it can store your configurations very easily and you can retrieve them so easily
[Flutter SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: The problem with SharedPreferences is; if you store sensible data, other apps using this package will be able to see it.